# Shiro: Is there a method to get permission list,which is difined by @RequiresPermissions annotation,in my project

Tags: security, permissions, shiro

So I can assign permissions to Roles from this list，or should I must store these permissions in database? Sometimes, I am not sure wether they are  the same.

For example,if there are @RequiresPermissions like

```
@RequiresPermissions("resourceA:create")
@RequiresPermissions("resourceA:update,delete")
@RequiresPermissions("resourceA:read")
@RequiresPermissions("resourceB:create,read,update,delete")
```

I can get permissions list like:

```
["resourceA:create","resourceA:update","resourceA:delete","resourceA:read",
"resourceB:create","resourceB:update","resourceB:delete","resourceB:read"]
```

or like

```
{"resourceA":{"create","update","delete","read"},
"resourceB":{"create","update","delete","read"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring permissions like this is just for shiro to use them to check if they match what a user can do, it is never meant to be exposed via an API.

If you really want to be able to query permissions, you are better of using a JdbcRealm, putting them in a database so you can query them.